# Div text and button does not center to middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I created a landing page like below:

[image]

I place the text and buttons in a div container and the alignment is correct but I am trying to move it below the logo so it looks naturally better. I tried using `bottom` to adjust the positioning but it does not reflect anything.

My code:

```
<body style="font-family:Verdana;color:#aaaaaa;">


        <div class="backgroundImage logo">
            <a href="/registrations/dealer "  class="btn grad1" style="float:right;"><b>{{ __('SIGN UP AS A DEALER') }}</b></a>


                    <div class="container" >                  
                        <h1 > A home is made of <i>
                       <p >hopes</p></i> and <i><p >dreams</p>  </i>
                        </h1>
                    <h1 >Let us<i> <p >inspire</p></i> you to build the perfect home!</h1> <br>

                    <a href="/login "  class="btn grad1" ><b>{{ __('LOGIN') }}</b></a>
                    <a href="/register"  class="btn grad1"><b>{{ __('SIGN UP') }}</b></a>
                </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

SASS:

```
.backgroundImage {
    background-image: url(/images/homepage.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


a.btn {
    color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fbcc34;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
}

.a {
    top: 50%;
}

p {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 75px;
    font-family: "Dancing Script" cursive;
    font-family: "Tangerine", cursive;
}

text-align: center;
position: relative;
top: 50%;

// Add media query for mobile devices

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 120%;
        float: left;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 170%;
    }

    .backgroundImage {
        background-image: url(/images/homepage.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out why is it not positioning to the center?

Edit:
The positioning is now fixed but however when I switch to mobile layout, it goes like below:

[image]

How do I center the first sentence?

Answer (score 2):

so you have to set position so bottom,left,right,top works!

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 30px;
}
```

Try that!

Comment: is position relative needed?

Comment: The position itself needed only! Then you can select what kind of position!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to move only button or along with that text too? If you want to move only button use this:

```
 <div class="backgroundImage logo">
        <a href="/registrations/dealer "  class="btn grad1" style="float:right;"><b>{{ __('SIGN UP AS A DEALER') }}</b></a>

<div style="padding-top:40%"></div>
                <div class="container" >                  
                    <h1 > A home is made of <i>
                   <p >hopes</p></i> and <i><p >dreams</p>  </i>
                    </h1>
                <h1 >Let us<i> <p >inspire</p></i> you to build the perfect home!</h1> <br>

                <a href="/login "  class="btn grad1" ><b>{{ __('LOGIN') }}</b></a>
                <a href="/register"  class="btn grad1"><b>{{ __('SIGN UP') }}</b></a>
            </div>

</div>
```

Or you want to bring only buttons just replace that div before the button.

And I'm not sure about here 40%, please give which will suit you. Many would say it's not a proper way to get the result but we can do as this too.

Comment: Hi, I want to move both text and button. However using position relative and top works but in mobile layout, the first sentence of text is not in middle anymore.why?

Comment: if your using bootstrap use class of d-flex. if not write class of .text-center{position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;} this may help you.

Comment: i am not using bootstrap. How do I make my image look better fit in mobile?

Comment: what do you mean by image? are you telling about that background logo or what?

Comment: The background image including the logo are 1 picture. If I shrink it to mobile layout, it looks like the screenshot above, not natural. Is there a way to make it better?

Comment: in your background image class change height and width by 100%. coz usually % will set on depending upon browser height and width.

Comment: changing to 100% will cause the image to not cover the entire screen in desktop

Answer (score 0):

Try the `margin-top` property, for example: `<div class="container" style="margin-top: 200px;">`.

Comment: Look at your `@media (max-width: 767px) {`, you defined `float: left` to the `h1`. Try removing that.

Comment: No, it makes the text even out of alignment in mobile view